# How can I use python aiohttp with OAuth1 to log into an OAuth1 service?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert the OAuth1 ETrade example (uses requests and rauth and requests) into an async app using aiohttp and oauthlib.

Can get up to step 3 but it come back with "Error - Token is invalid, or has expired"

Any guidance would be a huge help.

```
import oauthlib.oauth1
import aiohttp
import asyncio

# Etrade uses OAuth1
# Step 1: Get OAuth 1 request token and secret
# Step 2: Go through the authentication flow. Login to E*TRADE
# Step 3: Exchange the authorized request token for an authenticated OAuth 1 session

async def get_request_token(session:aiohttp.ClientSession,client:oauthlib.oauth1.Client):

    uri = 'https://api.etrade.com/oauth/request_token'
  
    # Sign the request data. This needs to be called for each request you make.
    uri,headers,body = client.sign(uri)

    values = dict()
    async with session.get(uri,headers=headers,raise_for_status=True) as r:
        data = await r.read()
 
        strdata = data.decode()
        parts = strdata.split('&')
        for part in parts:
            items = part.split('=')
            values[items[0]] = items[1]
    return values

async def get_verifier(client_key:str,request_token:str):
    print('-'*100)
    print('--- get_verifier')
    authorize_url = 'https://us.etrade.com/e/t/etws/authorize?key={}&token={}'.format(client_key,request_token)
  
    print('Etrade client setup (Must be done daily)')
    print('Log into this URL via your browser and paste the code here')
    print(authorize_url)
    text_code = input('Paste:')
    return text_code

async def get_access_token(session:aiohttp.ClientSession,client:oauthlib.oauth1.Client):

    uri = 'https://api.etrade.com/oauth/access_token'
 
    uri,headers,body = client.sign(uri)

    async with session.get(uri,headers=headers,raise_for_status=False) as r:
        data = await r.read()
        print('access token')
        print(data)
        # ERROR = Token is invalid, or has expired
        
async def main():
    # Create the Client. This can be reused for multiple requests.

    client_key = 'KEY HERE'
    client_secret = 'SECRET HERE'

    client = oauthlib.oauth1.Client(
        client_key = client_key,
        client_secret = client_secret,
        callback_uri='oob',
    )
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    # Step 1: Get OAuth 1 request token and secret
    values = await get_request_token(session,client)

    # Step 2: Go through the authentication flow. Login to E*TRADE
    client.verifier = await get_verifier(client_key,values['oauth_token'])
    client.resource_owner_key = values['oauth_token']
    client.resource_owner_secret = values['oauth_token_secret']

    # Step 3: Exchange the authorized request token for an authenticated OAuth 1 session
    # ERROR = Token is invalid, or has expired
    ok = await get_access_token(session,client)

    await session.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Pretty much ran out of ideas, have been diving into the rauth source trying to figure out why it works and why my code does not. The oauthlib documentaiton is sparse.

Comment: Answered my own question    async with session.get(uri,headers=headers,raise_for_status=True) as r:
        data = await r.read()
        datadict = parse_qs(data)
        for k,v in datadict.items():
            values[k.decode()] = v[0].decode()
    return values